# Multiple WHERE statements in URL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP page I created for an RSS feed.
This pulls courses for a school.

In the URL, I added locationid (to filter by location) and course parent (which filters by school).

URL structure is currently index.php?locid=1&tsid=2 (ts = training site)
THis pulls all courses that have locationid=1 and the training site id = 2
Works perfect.

The issue is that now we need to be able to pull two locations from URL SO locid=1 OR =2
I was thinking of adding another variable (?locid=1&locid2=2) but then I am limited to two locations in this query. Even if How to I make it intelligent enough to use parenthesis if there is two WHERE (locationid=1 OR locationid=2)

Is there an intelligent way to do this?

HEre is the code.

```
$where = array();
if (isset($_GET['tsid'])) {
$trainingsite = $_GET['tsid'];
$where[] = 'scheduledcourses.courseparent = '. $trainingsite ."";
}
if (isset($_GET['locid'])) {
$locationid = $_GET['locid'];
$where[] = 'scheduledcourses.courselocationid = '. $locationid ."";
}
if(count($where) >= 0) { array_unshift($where,""); } 
$where = implode(" AND ", $where); 
$where;
```

And here is the WHERE statement in the query

```
WHERE coursedate >= CURRENT_DATE() AND privatecourse='no' AND  $where";
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: if I understand your question correctly, you want to create your mysql query dynamically on base of configuration parameter which is numeric num. Am I correct?

Comment: There's an invisible elephant in the room: SQL injection! By crying out loud, why is everybody here intent on getting the OP's website hacked immediately? At least a hint of SQL injection would suffice, for example by checking that all ids are really numeric.

Answer (score 1):

You can use arrays in your url parameters aswell.

For example:

```
http://yourdomain.com/?locid[]=1&locid[]=2
```

This will result in:

```
print_r ( $_GET['locid'] );
Result:
array( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )
```

So then you get (just as an example. Edit this to fit your needs):

```
if( is_array( $_GET['locid'] ) && !empty( $_GET['locid'] ) ){
    $where = "";
    foreach( $_GET['locid'] AS $locid) {
        $where .= "AND locid = '$locid' ";
    }
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE something = something $where";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also seperate your IDs by a delimiter, like ',' so your URL looks like:

```
index.php?locid=1,2,3&tsid=4,6,234
```

Then you can explode it with explode() in PHP to an array and use this for your request.

```
$locidArray = explode(',', $_GET['locid']);
```

Comment: Much better to use array access notation in this case I would think.

Comment: It all depends on how beautiful you want your URL look like, array access notation is maybe more correct but doesn't look so good. And this is not so much more complicated to use.

Comment: @MikeBrant, no I don't think that it's «much better». It's just one of the possible ways.

Comment: @nalply It is pretty much industry standard way to pass arrays of data via GET/POST.  Note all the other answers on this thread which popped up within minutes advocating this approach.  Pretty consistent response to this need.

Comment: @MikeBrant When the sheeps all march in one direction to the abyss (SQL injection) I am glad to go the other direction. When someone says «industry standard» I am happy that I am self-employed and don't need to do what a stupid boss tells me.

Comment: @Matthias, and don't forget to validate the IDs that they are really numeric. If you don't do that, your public website will be hacked within days.

Comment: @nalply Yes, validation is always something you have to do, just wanted to just answer the question.

Comment: @nalply The SQL injection vulnerability has nothing to do with how the parameters are passed.  I think you rightfully noted the SQL injection vulnerability in the comments to the question, but it is irrelevant with regards to how to pass arrays of data.  Some standards are standards for a reason. What happens the next time the OP wants to pass an array of data from a group of similar form fields?  Is he going to use javascript to concatenate the values into a comma-separated string for posting?  Is he going to resort the to amateur approach of naming the fields foo1, foo2, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

If you make your URL such way:

```
index.php?locid[]=1&locid[]=2
```

you will get in PHP script in `$_GET['locid']` an Array with values [1,2] and can work with it:

```
foreach($_GET['locid'] as $locid) {
    echo $locid.'<br>';
}
```

to use in mysql query:

```
$where = '`locid` IN ('.implode(',', $_GET['locid']).')';
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use array access notation to pass an array of data via get.  That could look like this:

```
index.php?locid[]=1&locid[]=2&tsid=2
```

PHP will automatically take parameters of same name with `[]` or `[foo]` notation and assemble them into an array accessible at the parameter name `$_GET['locid']` in your case.

Comment: And don't forget to validate the data to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: @nalply Indeed that would need to be done here as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could make locid an arry in the GET instead of the single value it is now. For example:

```
http://link/myids.php?locid[]=1&locid[]=2&locid[]=3
```

Then in the `if (isset($_GET['locid'])) {`

```
$first = true;
foreach ( locid as $_GET['locid'] ) {
    if ( first ) {
        first = false;
        $where[] = 'scheduledcourses.courselocationid = '. $locationid ."";
    } else {
        $where[] = ' AND scheduledcourses.courselocationid = '. $locationid ."";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use an array of ids in the get request like

```
index.php?locid[]=1&locid[]=2&tsid=2
```

and then when checking the parameter you loop over the array

```
if (isset($_GET['locid'])) {
if(is_array($_GET['locid']){
    $tmpOrWhere = array();
    foreach($_GET['locid'] as $locid){
        $tmpOrWhere[] = 'scheduledcourses.courselocationid = '. $locid."";
    }
    $where[] = "(" . implode (" OR " , $tmpOrWhere) . ")";
}else{
    $locationid = $_GET['locid'];
    $where[] = 'scheduledcourses.courselocationid = '. $locationid ."";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array syntax in the url:

```
index.php?locid[]=1&locid[]=3&locid[]=7&tsid=2
```

then you php becomes:

```
if (isset($_GET['locid'])) {
    $locationid = $_GET['locid'];
    if(is_array($locationid)){
        $where[] = 'scheduledcourses.courselocationid IN('. implode(',', $locationid) .')';
    }else{
        $where[] = 'scheduledcourses.courselocationid = '. $locationid;
    }
}
```